# I want to send email to certain locations in certain radius and I keep getting these two error codes and have no idea what Im doing wrong

Tags: php

These are the two error codes I keep getting:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   Operation timed out"

and

> "PDO->__construct"

I have just started php coding and Im not sure what to do in this situtiation and I would apriciate some help.

```
$servername = "yourservername";
$username = "yourusername";
$password = "yourpassword";
$dbname = "yourdbname";


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


error_log($_POST['name']);


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO urakka (name,email,address,neliometrit,urakankuvaus)
VALUES (:name,:email,:address,:neliometrit,:urakankuvaus)");



  $name = $_POST['name'];

  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $address = $_POST['address'];

  $neliometrit = $_POST['neliometrit'];

  $urakankuvaus = $_POST['urakankuvaus'];


$stmt->execute(array("name" => $name,"email" => $email, "address" => $address, "neliometrit" => $neliometrit, "urakankuvaus" => $urakankuvaus));

$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
$output= json_decode($geocode);
$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lon = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *,(((acos(sin((60*pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180))+cos((60*pi()/180))
  * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((21- longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)
  AS distance FROM firmat HAVING distance <= 2000 ORDER BY distance ASC;");
$stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $output)  {
        error_log($output["email"]);

        require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = "smtp.postmarkapp.com";
        $mail->Port = 26;
        $mail->Username = "youremail";
        $mail->Password = "yourpassword";

        $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'Web App');
        $mail->Subject = "A Transactional Email From Web App";
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->AddAddress($address, $name);

        if($mail->Send()) {
          echo "Message sent!";
        } else {
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

echo('done');
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? That query can't be indexed, so it will have to calculate the distance for every row in the table. Maybe you should look into using a spacial index instead of using the Haversine formula.

Comment: Also, another way to do this may be to get a table of zipcodes that have lat long values in the table.  Then you query the table for the distances via the lat/long and return the zipcodes inside the area.  Then use the zipcodes to query your final table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that both of those errors are related to the connection to the server not being established.

Try wrapping your connection in a try catch to see some errors.

If you don't see the errors at least you know it's not your connection.

```
try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```